# $product->getOptions() behavior inconsistent

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, programmatically

If I run code to load a product and its options in a product view template file *app/design/frontend/mymodule/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml*

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);
$options = $product->getOptions();
```

it works as expected. However, if I run the ***same code*** for the ***same product*** in a controller of my custom module `$options` is an empty array.

Is there some initialization code I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 <?php

    $productID = 45

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID);
    $options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getProductOptionCollection($product);

    foreach ($options as $option) {
        Mage::log('Name: ' . $option->getDefaultTitle());
        Mage::log('    Type: ' . $option->getType());
        Mage::log('    Class: ' . get_class($option));
        Mage::log('    Price/Type: ' . ($option->getPrice() ? $option->getPrice() : '0.00') . ' / ' . $option->getType());

        if ($option->getType() === 'drop_down') {
            $values = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option_value')->getValuesCollection($option);
            Mage::log('    Values: (name/price/type)');

            foreach ($values as $value) {
                Mage::log('        ' . $value->getTitle() . ' / ' . $value->getPrice() . ' / ' . $value->getPriceType());;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

for configurable products, you can get product option like below:

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productId);
$productAttributeOptions =$product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
$attributeOptions = array();
foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
    foreach ($productAttribute['values'] as $attribute) {
        $attributeOptions[$productAttribute['label']] [$attribute['value_index']] = $attribute['store_label'];
    }
}
```

I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: No dice - `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getConfigurableAttributesAsArray()`

Comment: above code will load the options of configurable product and as i can see you are passing simple product object..that why its giving error.

Comment: Ah, maybe revise the answer to state it works for configurable products. in my case I have simple products.